# How to hide query params when redirecting from php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, url, uri

I have an index.php page, that does a POST request. After the post request I create a query string

PHP code snippet : - index.php

```
// example url : /some-route?&email=test@abc.com&first_name=test
 $url: "/some-route?&email=".trim($_POST["email"])."&first_name=" . 
 trim($_POST["firstName"]);
 header('Location: '.$url);
```

This is pointed to angular js routing file

Angular js - > stateProviderfile -> states.js

```
     $stateProvider
   .state("some-route", {
     url: '/some-route?isSomeApp',
     templateUrl : 'app/components/application/some-
                   information/someView.html',
     controller : 'someCtrl',
     params: { isSomeApp: null},
     data: { public: true }
});
```

Now I want to retrieve values in the Query parameter and store it in $scope variable so that I can auto populate text fields in someView.html
Code that I use in someCtrl.js is :

```
enter code here
$scope.parse = function(){
    if ($scope.params["first_name"] != undefined) {
      $scope.firstname = $scope.params["first_name"];
     }


   if ($scope.params["email"] != undefined) {
      $scope.email = $scope.params["email"];
     }
}

// call the above function in init() in someCtrl.js
$scope.init = function(){
    $scope.params = $location.search();
  if (Object.keys($scope.params).length > 0) {
     $scope.parseParams();
  }
}
```

My questions is : How do I hide first_name and email in url so that it is not visible to end users but yet have it in some way so that I can access it someCtrl.js

I want that the users see : /some-route

My code sees : example url : /some-route?
   &email=test@abc.com&first_name=test

I want actual url to have hidden params email and first_name 
 - so users don't see that information and
 - I can access it from my code

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can not hide the URL params in a GET call. You need to use a POST call for that.

Comment: how can I add a post call in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a POST call with only two parameters (Name and E-mail) and you like to hide the params, use an HTML page instead of PHP File with a form and when the user submits that, make the POST petition in your AngularJS controller with the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

Keep rocking!